# What are mi yodeya's standards for rejecting potentially offensive content?

Tags: discussion, flagging, offensive-content

What are the guidelines for flagging questions/answers as offensive on mi yodeya? Often, there are postings that ironically ask about halachic applicability of e.g. the principle of mishum eiva, which themselves seem to be violations of that principle, posting content that could easily be misconstrued/misused as offensive to non-Jews. Perhaps some of the back-and-forths are more appropriate for more private forums...

Comment: Do you mean to ask generally "What are the guidelines for flagging questions/answers as offensive on mi yodeya?" (as you ask in fact), or do you mean to ask something more specific, or even something different?

Comment: @msh210 the general guidelines as well as to perhaps open the discussion a bit if those guidelines don't seem to conform fully to halachik expectations.

Comment: Related? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/123/5323

Comment: This is for Judaism, so when other people browse here, they need to be  that not everything will go so well with them. On the other hand, there's the problem of eiva, chilul Hashem... I guess it requires common sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use common sense to determine what is acceptable to post and what is better discussed elsewhere.

Posters need to be cognizant that their posts are read by a wide variety of people, Jews and non-Jews in various places with various perspectives.

People need to exercise responsibility and prudence in everything published online or in any open forum.

Answer (score 2):

> אבטליון אומר, חכמים, היזהרו בדבריכם--שמא תחובו חובת גלות, ותגלו למקום המים הרעים, וישתו התלמידים הבאים אחריכם וימותו, ונמצא שם שמיים מתחלל

[Avos 1:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h49.htm) tells the scholar to be careful with his words, lest they result in a Chillul Hashem.